# How do I change the background color of the upper right hand corner of VS Code?

Tags: background, visual-studio-code

Can someone please tell me the workbench.colorCustomizations option to change the background color of the upper right area of VS code? It is driving me crazy going through all the options and I can't find it. Is there a guide that tells you what all of these areas are? It is so hard to guess what the tags means.
I have a theme that I like but I just want to darken the background because it is a bit too light for my eyes.
[image: Top Right Hand Corner of Vs Code]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Visual Studio Code's tab bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67960052/change-visual-studio-codes-tab-bar-color)

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for the area where the tabs are placed, which includes under those split, etc., icons to the right:

`"editorGroupHeader.tabsBackground": "#ff0000"`

see in general https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-groups-tabs

from [theme color reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) that is the best source for figuring what applies where.